# Same content (language) for multiple countries (store views)

Tags: magento2, language, static-content, locale, country-regions

I'm trying to implement an e-commerce site (using **Magento 2**) that has the following requirements:

1. be available in **N** countries (eg `http://example.com/country_code/` )
2. with **X** languages
3. share the same price
4. Currency changes depending on the selected country

The initial idea is to create 1x website with 1x store with **N** store-views

However, I wanted to reuse the content in countries that share the same language base (eg: English in the US and UK)

It becomes impracticable to add or change the same content to several different store-views.

Do you know the best Magento practice to handle this issue, or if there is a module from a Magento partner to manage a multi-locale and multi-language store?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution ?
I have the same "issue"